# Java Web application Sockets error 404 during handshake

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-applications, glassfish

New to using web sockets and attempting to make a collaborative whiteboard, using java on IntelliJ and glassfish web applications, however, I have a 404 error trying to test an HTTP handshake to show the connection is working.

My Server side endpoint looks like this:

`@ServerEndpoint(value = "/wboardendpoint") public class boardServer { ... }`

My javascript wsUri specifing the names and declaring the endpoint:

`let wsUri = "ws://localhost:8080/ColloborativeWhiteBoard/wboardendpoint"; let websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);`

[Attached is my project structure, in case this is an issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN6q7.png)

[Attached is the error message I get while trying to connect to a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFCZ2.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>ColloborativeWhiteBoard</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ColloborativeWhiteBoard</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: A 404 code means that you have requested a resource that is not there / not valid

Comment: Thank you, I understand that, is there any resource that you know that can help me as the tutorial I am using described the code in the way I did it.

Comment: The connection URL I've been using to connect from JavaScript to a local ratchet server is: ws://localhost:8080, which is working for me. I wonder if part of your problem is the part after // ? You might want to try pinging localhost:8080 to make sure it's up and receiving and responding to connections

Comment: Right my localhost 8080 seems to be responding, could I ask what version of glassfish and JDK is required for this, as from a few tutorials I've seen they use glassfish 4 and JDK 1.8. but I am using glassfish 6 and JDK 15 also is the dependency i am using correct as I'm using javax.

Comment: ... "what version ..." I've no idea. As I said, I used Ratchet (PHP) for the server side.